# Fixed size matrix and Maybe

Tags: types, purescript

I am writing a board game in PureScript that involves a matrix of exact size 2x7 (in certain variations it can be 4x7).  The package I’m using has a [`Matrix.getRow`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-matrices/2.0.0/docs/Matrix#v:getRow) function that returns a `Maybe (Array a)`.

What is the best approach to **not** have to deal with `Maybe` returns when I know for sure that `Matrix.getRow 0` is always going to return the first row (because the matrix is of fixed size 2x7)?

Currently I have ugly code to deal with Maybes which is obviously not very desirable:

```
notPossible :: Array Cell
notPossible = [99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99]  -- never used

row n = fromMaybe notPossible $ Matrix.getRow n state.cells
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PureScript uses the type system to track partiality, where partiality is the property that a function does not produce a return value for all possible inputs.

If you want to circumvent the type system and guarantee yourself that you will not pass invalid inputs you can use the `Partial.Unsafe.unsafePartial :: forall a. (Partial => a) -> a` function from the `purescript-partial` package.

By using the partial function `fromJust` from `Data.Maybe`

```
Data.Maybe.fromJust :: forall a. Partial => Maybe a -> a
```

you can then construct your unsafe row function:

```
unsafeRow n xs = unsafePartial fromJust (Matrix.getRow n xs)
```

You can also delay calling unsafePartial to a point at which you can guarantee that your index is never out of bounds, as the type system will propagate it automatically for you.